# Catan pirates and explorers ships and roads

Tags: catan

In Catan Explorers and Pirates, can a ship share a hex side with a road?

[image]

Comment: It is worth pointing out the distinction between the question of if a ship in Explorers and Pirates can share a space with a road versus if a ship in Seafarers of Catan can share a space with a road.  For Seafarers, the rules specifically state "You may not build a ship along a coast route if there is already a road along that hex side (and vice versa)" however this rule does not apply to the exact question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 2 ships and a road can share a coastline.

According to the FAQ for Catan Pirates and Explorers:

> Sea Routes - Are only ships allowed on "sea routes" located between
> terrain hexes and sea hexes / frame, or may I also build roads there?
>
> Roads may be built on all paths, both inland and along the coast. At
> the shore, roads can be parallel to ships, meaning that up to 1 road +
> 2 ships may simultaneously occupy a path on the coast.

Source :
[Catan FAQ page 157](https://www.catan.com/faq-page/157)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at rules [here] I see no reason why not[1](https://www.catan.com/download/6682/catan-explorers-pirates-rules-3-4-players)  Small Caveat, I've never played this expansion but the rules seem fairly clear.

Firstly I can't find anything in the rules that prohibits this.  If this was not allowed I believe it would be explicitly stated. The rules do include very details rules about the building a movement of ships.  The following all make me think its fine as well

The rules define a Sea Route as :-

> The edges of a sea hex are called sea routes.  Sea routes separate sea hexes from each other and terrain hexes from sea hexes.

So if the ship is in a sea route than it cant be in same space as the road which is on land.

In the rules for building ships it states :-

> When you build a ship, place it on a sea route directly adjacent to one of your harbour settlements, with the following conditions:

None of the following conditions say that you cant build a ship a sea route next to a road.